# Location of variables in a network (Network Analysis)

Tags: r, network-analysis

If some variables are located at the TOP of the network (when I conducted network analysis), does this make any difference? (Like compared to if the variables were located on the left side or below)

I lack knowledge about the position of variables in a network and need help to understand this please.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages); sample representative data using `dput(head(x))`, `data.frame(..)`, `read.table(..)`, or similar; and often actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: This question is 100% contextual, depending on what the network represents, is it directional, what does "top" really mean, what are the other attributes of the nodes, etc.

Comment: Remember, networks are an abstraction that you approximate a system through them. So it depends on what do you mean by variable? Are you talking about the label of the node or the node or the weight of the node? It depends on what the layout was meant to reflect, input nodes, output nodes, internal nodes, or ordering along other node semantics. In my experience, I did not need to worry about the position of nodes except perhaps in hierarchical trees and flux balance networks.

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for your reply. It is an undirected network. By "top", I mean the position of the variables in the network (just the upper side of the network). The nodes are psychological factors and I attributed them to 3 different groups.

Comment: @bioSlayer Thank you for your response. The variable represents a psychological factor. It is the node. The layout was meant to reflect how a set of input nodes affect a couple of output nodes or how they interact with each other.

Comment: *"I lack knowledge about the position of variables"*, I understand. Similarly, we lack knowledge about the network in general. Questions on SO need to be about programming problems, but I think your question is about the theory of how to do something, an academic discussion of sorts. I suggest this is more appropriate for [stats.se], though even there I think this question would benefit from a bit more detail. As it stands now, this question seems unlikely to garner actionable answers. Good luck!